# Mongoid <-> Atlas constant messages

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-atlas

I am evaluating MongoDB DBaas (Atlas).
I upgraded mongoid to 3.4 and connected (successfully) to the service.
Everything works ok, BUT:
My console keeps getting these messages all the time:

> MONGODB | Server description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from
>   'primary' to 'primary'. MONGODB | Server description for
>   xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'secondary' to 'secondary'. MONGODB |
>   Server description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'secondary' to
>   'secondary'. MONGODB | Server description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed
>   from 'secondary' to 'secondary'. MONGODB | Server description for
>   xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'. MONGODB | Server
>   description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'secondary' to
>   'secondary'. MONGODB | Server description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed
>   from 'secondary' to 'secondary'. MONGODB | Server description for
>   xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'. MONGODB | Server
>   description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'secondary' to
>   'secondary'. MONGODB | Server description for xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed
>   from 'primary' to 'primary'. MONGODB | Server description for
>   xxxxxxxxx:27017 changed from 'secondary' to 'secondary'.

1. Why is this happening as they are not really changing roles?
2. How can I disable these log messages?

> Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL

didn't work.

Thanks.